# How to make a pairing and mode button on a remote control receiver

Tags: rf, remote-control

I'm working on a remote control project and have come across many different RF receiver/transmitter modules. Many have a pairing/mode button on the receiver that serves to pair the receiver and transmitter and to choose which mode the transmitter is in, momentary, latching, toggle, etc.
[image]

How can I replicate this feature using Arduino and those cheap RF transmitter/receiver combos on Ebay? Specific code would be nice, but just a general idea as to how it would be done in theory will work too. I've watched several tutorials that explain the use of the Radiohead library with the cheap RF combos, but none demonstrate how to set up a feature such as this. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remote sends a number before the command bits. The receiver checks if this number is the same with the number that corresponds with the position of the switches.

You can do the same in software. Have the first few bits be some number. The receiver can then check if the first few bits of the received "message" matches that number. If it doesn't it will just throw it out.

This is the same method used with IR-remote controls. The signal from your VCR remote will also be received by your TV. But the TV sees that the code doesn't match the one it's expecting. So it will ignore those.